# Get response object from requestForObject even in case of exception (caused by Bad Request)

Tags: java, spring, rest, post, spring-boot

I have written some consument of `REST` using `spring boot`. It is working for me.

However, I would like to be able to get the body of response even in the case of `Bad request`. At this moment it throws an exception, however, I want to read error of message.

To be more precise:
Webservice always returns JSON, something like that:

```
{
  errorCode : 12,
  errorMessage: "Can't find element"
}
```

or

```
{
   errorCode : 0,
   errorMessage: ""
}
```

I have the corresponding model in my code:

```
class Response {
  int errorCode;
  String errorMessage;
}    
Request req = new Request();
Response response = restTemplate.postForObject(SOME_ENDPOINT, request,Response.class);
```

However, in the case of `BadRequest`, I can't get an error message (so response object) because it throws exception `RestClientException`.

How to suppress this exception and get a response ?